# How accessible is ring fit adventure

Tags: accessibility, ring-fit-adventure

I'd like to play Nintendo's Ring Fit Adventure, but I'm visually impaired, so I need to be close to the screen to see details.

Assuming I can't easily perform the exercises while being as close to the screen as I need to be, I'm wondering:

- Do I have control over how long text stays on screen, so I can go closer to read it?
- Are important gameplay elements contrasting enough with the background?
- Are there enough audio clues to make decisions?

Also, please leave info that could be useful for people with other disabilities.

Comment: Doesn't the switch have the zoom mode? Might help with text and showing remaining reps and stuff

Comment: Thx, I'll look into that!

Comment: [You can also put switch into Negative or GreyScale colors, depending on game and your eyes it might help with contrast (a bit)](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26318/~/how-to-change-the-display-colors)

Comment: "I need to be close to the screen to see details" Would using a projector help? Most people don't realise that a high quality 1080p home cinema projecter that produces a > 100" image costs less than what many people spend on TVs half the size. (As I write this there are some great options under $500 USD, and they are steadily getter better and cheaper over the years).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

During exercises there are sound effects to notify you when a move/pose is done. I sometimes even play while not looking at the screen without issue. Before starting, the ring and leg band need to be at a specific orientation. For example, when you do an overhead press, the ring needs to be horizontal. Tipp (the figure that shows you the moves) is visible including the text how you should be standing, and you have enough time to come closer to the screen to read this.

I cannot really say if the contrast is high enough. There are a lot of bright colors, also showing how much repetitions are left. Showing how moves are done is shown by Tipp with a white background, as shown in the screenshot below (this is actually before starting an exercise).

There are also parts in the game where you jog through a forest, grassland or something else. There you can do various things to obtain more coins, take shortcuts or evade enemies. Those moments cannot be paused or slowed down unfortunately. Maybe if you look at a gameplay video you might see if the contrast is high enough. Doing these things are not necessary though, you can still progress the game.

[image: Tipp explaining a squat]

Comment: I finally obtained ringy thingy and tested it without glasses (so I could not read text 1m from 50'' screen). Colors are too happy so everything turned into rainbow blur, but as I mentioned half a year ago switching Switch to [Black&White](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26318/~/how-to-change-the-display-colors) mode helps a lot with that.
In additions to contours, Voice guide, Tipp animations, and controller vibrations were enough to guide me through monster fights. However its still good to know how it all works before playing half-blind.